# What does "go out there" mean as used by athletes in baseball, basketball, etc

Tags: sports

Here is an interview with a Utah Jazz basketball player after the game:

> Donovan Mitchell acknowledged it was hard trying not to go all-out
> early on: "I had a moment before the game, I was talking to myself,
> trying to calm myself. … It’s easy to **go out there** and try to hit a
> home run early, but the game isn’t won in the first five minutes."

What does *go out there* mean?

Comment: The interesting part is the other *go-out* use here of "trying not to go **all-out** early on."

Comment: I think the interesting part is an NBA player trying to hit a home run....

Comment: Why leads you to wonder whether *go out there* means anything other than what it at face value appears to mean when each of its three words is taken literally?

Comment: @tchrist What makes me thinking that it means something else other than the face value is that basketball game happens **in** a stadium, I mean a building, not **out of** a building.

Comment: @YosefBaskin In fact my next question would had been *What does **go all-out** mean*?:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If someone is performing (an athlete or team player or person talking to an audience), **go out there** is used to mean:
go to the **place where the event is occurring**, a stage, a baseball field, and do [whatever], make baskets, hit a home run, hit under par (in golf).

When you **go out onto a field**, **you can be seen by the public**, as opposed to sitting on the bench, locker room or on the sidelines.

A basketball or baseball player would not use that idiom unless the public is seeing him or her. They would not use it in a closed practice session.

PLEASE NOTE: It is quite amusing that a basketball player chooses to use a baseball term. It shows the extent to which certain idioms permeate the language, even a pro ball player like this.

To hit a home run = score four points by running around the three bases and back to home plate. It is the highest number of points one person can get when playing baseball.

A typical comment might be: Go out there and knock 'em dead, kid.

go out, to be seen by the public, in this particular case.

Comment: In baseball you do not get one "point" for each base you traverse.  You only score 4 runs on a home run if the bases are loaded.

Comment: And to add to @KirkWoll's comment, if the bases are loaded and you hit a home run that would be a "grand slam".

Comment: On the home run point: I think the metaphor works here because a home run is the _quickest/most efficient_ way to score, not because it's the most points (that depends how many people are on the other bases when the HR is hit). Hitting a home run gives you one or more runs (points) immediately, but it doesn't help if you don't play well for the rest of the game.

Comment: This answer is great! Now I have a clear answer to *why out*. Being seen **publicly** is the key part. Thank you! @Lambie

Comment: Sorry, but as a former little leaguer...a homerun does NOT score 4 runs (1 for each base) unless "bases are loaded"--then it would be a "grand slam". Simply "knocking one out of the park" does not earn 4 runs, "one for each base."

Comment: @Cascabel Yeah, yeah, yeah, I forgot when the bases are loaded: You gotta have heart https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry8CpIg2fvU DAMN YANKEES! Listen to all of it if you don't know it. i

Answer (score 20):

***go out there***

in this case does ***not*** mean [crazy or weird](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out-there); it is literal.

It means ***go out there***  onto the  playing field, pitch,  court, battlefield, etc.

I would classify this as a *verb + particle + adverb*, but I am open to constructive criticism...

Comment: This applies metaphorically to all kinds of endeavors, not just sports, although that's where the usage probably started. So don't delete, please!

Comment: @Robusto It is possible that like "over there", this comes from the battlefield.  // For some reason I am reminded of Captain Kirk standing on the bridge, replying to the question "Where do we go now?"

Comment: I don't see any reason why this is connected with a military expression. In some sports (e.g. baseball, cricket) the rules mean that every player does not take part in the entire game, but only when it is their turn to bat. In professional sports where substitute players are commonly used (basketball, American football, soccer) the same logic applies.